# Implication of the Symmetry of the Christoffel Symbol

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensors, general-relativity

The Christoffel symbols are defined by $\frac{\partial \mathbf{e}_\alpha}{\partial x^\mu} \equiv \Gamma_{\mu \alpha}^\nu \mathbf{e}_\nu$. We also know that the Christoffel symbols are symmetric in their lower two indices. This appears to imply that $\frac{\partial \mathbf{e}_\alpha}{\partial x^\mu} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{e}_\mu}{\partial x^\alpha}$ for all coordinate bases, which seems unlikely. Is this true?

Comment: Carefull : $\langle \frac{\partial e_{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\mu}},  e_{\beta} \rangle = \Gamma^{\beta}_{\mu\alpha}$.

Comment: @Sou What does this show?

Answer (score 0):

The Christoffel symbols are a set of coefficent that describe a connection. To understand the latter, you can read the most general case (at least known to me) on [Natural Operations in Differential Geormetry](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwij7o-Dr_LdAhVHlxoKHVXiB4cQFjAAegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mat.univie.ac.at%2F~michor%2Fkmsbookh.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3l-CUexbOlBL8ebiz4mW5H) (chapters II and III).

However to grasp the concept there is no need to use such formality. One can simply define a map $\nabla: \mathfrak{X}(M) \times \mathfrak{X}(M)  \rightarrow \mathfrak{X}(M) :(X,Y) \mapsto \nabla_X(Y)$ with the following properties:
$$
 \forall f \in C^{\infty}(M) \space\ \nabla_{fX}Y=f \nabla_{X}Y, \space\ \nabla_{X}fY=X(f)+ f\nabla_{X}Y,
$$
$$
\nabla_{X}(Y+Z)=\nabla_{X}Y+\nabla_{X}Z, \space\ \nabla_{X_1+X_2}Y=\nabla_{X_1}Y+\nabla_{X_2}Y
$$
If you express in coordinate $(x^{\mu},\partial_{\mu}:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}})$ this map by defining $\nabla_{\partial_{\mu}}\partial_{\nu}:= \Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\alpha} \partial_{\alpha}$, you get that
$$
\nabla_XY=X^{\mu}\frac{\partial Y^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\partial_{\alpha}+X^{\mu}Y^{\nu}\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\alpha} \partial_{\alpha}
$$
given locally $X=X^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$ and $X=X^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}$. In general there is no need for the coefficients $\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\alpha}$ to be symmetric, however when this happens we say that the connection is *torsionless*. It can be shown that this happens iff the *torsion* $T:\mathfrak{X}(M) \times \mathfrak{X}(M)  \rightarrow \mathfrak{X}(M)$ defined by $T(X,Y)=\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX - [X,Y]$ is zero. Among torsionless connections there is one which is special, that is the Levi-Civita connection for which 
$$
\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\alpha}=\frac{1}{2} g^{\alpha \beta} (\partial_{\mu}g_{\nu \alpha}+\partial_{\nu}g_{\alpha \mu}-\partial_{\alpha}g_{\mu \nu} )
$$
where $g$ is a Riemannian metric, if that happens we call the connection *metric*. Such expressions take the name of Christoffel symbols. Back to your question, any torsionless connection, thus not only for metric connections, $\nabla$ will have $\nabla_{\partial_{\mu}}\partial_{\nu}= \Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\alpha} \partial_{\alpha}=\Gamma_{\nu \mu}^{\alpha} \partial_{\alpha}=\nabla_{\partial_{\nu}}\partial_{\mu}$.