# The basic commutation in evolution of Ricci flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Many references compute the evolution equation in Ricci flow like this, for example compute the evolution of Christoffel symbols
$$\partial_{t} \Gamma^{k}_{ij} = {}  \frac{1}{2}\partial_{t}(g^{kl}(\partial_{i} g_{jl} + \partial_{j} g_{il} - \partial_{l} g_{ij}))  \\  = {} \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{t}g^{kl})(\partial_{i} g_{jl} + \partial_{j} g_{il} - \partial_{l} g_{ij}) +  \frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(\partial_{t} \partial_{i} g_{jl} + \partial_{t} \partial_{j} g_{il} - \partial_{t} \partial_{l} g_{ij})  =   \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{t}g^{kl})(\partial_{i} g_{jl} + \partial_{j} g_{il} - \partial_{l} g_{ij}) +  \frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(\partial_{i} \partial_{t}  g_{jl} + \partial_{j} \partial_{t}  g_{il} - \partial_{l}  \partial_{t} g_{ij})$$
I am puzzled about why the equation $\partial_{t} \partial_{l}  g_{ij} =  \partial_{l} \partial_{t}  g_{ij}$ can hold? Since all common derivatives on natural frame can commute? I am not sure the real reasons.

Comment: If $(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ are local coordinates on $M$, then $(t,x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ are local coordinates on $I\times M$ where $I$ is some interval, so that $(\partial_t,\partial_1,\ldots,\partial_n)$ come from some coordinates and indeed commute.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2945002/305862) found using the formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/